# I do not understand the syntax of docker-compose: "volumes" and "services"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I don't understand the syntax of the docker-compose-file.
First of all

```
version: '3'
services:
  bla:
    command: /bin/bash    
    stdin_open: true
    #tty: true
    container_name: docker-gulp-template
    #restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/html/bla-source"

volumes:
  volumes-xyz:
```

If I execute it with

```
docker-compose up
```

It does create a container with the name

```
docker-gulp-template_bla
```

But that sounds illogical to me, though. Shouldn't the container be called this way:

```
bla_docker-gulp-template ?
```

Why was it solved like this? Does any of you have an example?

And another point:

```
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/html/bla-source"

volumes:
  volumes-xyz:
```

Why do I need the second volumes command and how does docker know that the first volume path belongs to the other volumes name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the volume section.

A volume can be a named volume, created under the top level `volumes` section, like

```
volumes:
  volumes-xyz:
```

and mounted under a service with

```
 volumes:
      - "volumes-xyz:/usr/src/html/bla-source"
```

Named volumes are managed by docker (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on Linux).

Volume can also be anonymous by

```
 volumes:
      - "/usr/src/html/bla-source"
```

`- ".:/usr/src/html/bla-source"`, on the other hand, creates a "bind mount". It's very similar to volume but you can choose its path to create a two-way mapping between your container and the host.

Comment: I don't know your compose version, but `container_name` should give a container with exactly that name

Comment: Thank you for this answer! 
For what do I need the 

`volumes:
volumes-xyz:`

`volumes:
      - "volumes-xyz:/usr/src/html/bla-source"`

function excatly? It sounds odd to me to create a volume on a container without the two-way binding between the container and the host. Could someone please give me a "real" example?

Thanks a lot! Best answer! :)

Comment: I may not be very clear on that: all 3 forms create a two-way binding between the host and the container but these 2 forms do not allow you to choose a path. An example: If you host a database instance with docker and do not want to specify location to put the data, this is the option to use.